# Suburbia - what is the rule of Reputation?

Tags: suburbia

**Introduction**

In [Suburbia](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/123260/suburbia) you track your population, reputation, and income. The goal is to have the most population when the cards run out. Income is needed to purchase tiles to increase your population.

**Question**

As I understand from what the rules say about reputation is that in the event of a tie with population at the end of the game,  the one with the highest reputation is the winner. My question is, does reputation do anything else in the game other than that? If that's the only reason for it, and ties are pretty unlikely, I have no reason to keep it up.

Comment: please verify that the link I added is the game you referring (just Suburbia, not "CIties Suburbia").  If that the case, then reputation determine the amount of population that is added each turn.

Comment: In the subject line, do you mean "role of Reputation"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reputation = number of people that added to the total, at the end of the turn.

The relevant part in the rules:

[image]

> ### ADJUST POPULATION (BASED ON REPUTATION)
>
> Increase or decrease your Population on the Population Board by the amount where your Reputation Cube is located. If Population gets to 0, any additional movements backwards cost $1 per Population. If the player cannot pay this fee, nothing happens to the player...he just stays on the 0 spot.
>
> As your borough grows, it will cost more to maintain and its “small town” quality will decrease --
> this is represented by Red Lines on the population track. When a player’s Population crosses a Red
> Line, then that player’s Income ◯ and Reputation █ are both reduced by 1 (moved to the left one
> space) for every Red Line the player moves past. If a player’s Population dips below a Red Line (this
> can happen if he has a negative Reputation) he moves both his Income Cylinder and his Reputation
> Cube forward (moved to the right one space).

Comment: It's probably worth copying the relevant text of the rules to the answer as links to images may not last forever.